# python3 pandas - #TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, string, pandas, int, typeerror

Could you please support me to clarify the proper way to convert a selected Dataframe column into string ?

'Product_ID' part of dataframe 'df' is automatically selected as integer

If I use following statement:

```
df['Product_ID']=df['Product_ID'].to_string()
```

generate error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

same issue is generated by `.astype(str)` or `.apply(str)`

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `to_string` and `.astype(str)` do different things. `to_string` returns a single string, and `.astype(str)` returns a series with string values. Which are you trying to do?

Second, how sure are you that you are working with an integer series? What does `df['Product_ID'].dtype` return?

Third, can you try to post a reproducible example? One way to narrow down the data that is causing the problem:

```
for i,v in enumerate(df['Product_ID'].values):
    try:
        str(v)
    except TypeError:
        print i, v
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I used the command : TypeCheck  = df.dtypes and verified that 'Product_ID' is 'int64'...   I tried to add a new column df['Project_ID_textcopy'] = df['Project_ID'].to_string() and this work properly.  it seems that the issue is generated when i ask to override in same line the column itself df['Project_ID'] = df['Project_ID'].to_string()

Comment: Interesting, I'm still not able to reproduce this.